# jQuery validate equalTo

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I would like to use jQuery validate() plugin using the equalTo to validate a signature field, basically the signature field must match the first name and last name field, is this possible using the validate() plugin?

http://jqueryvalidation.org/equalTo-method/ shows me how to check if it is equal to another input, but can it do like the following?

equalTo: field1 + field2

as oppose to

equalTo: field1,

basically what I'm asking is can we concatenate 2 fields and use that in the validate() plugin?

```
                    <li>
                        <label>
                            First Name <span class="form-required">*</span>
                        </label>
                        <div>
                            <input type="text" class="form-textbox"  id="first_name" name="first_name" size="20" value="" required/>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label>
                            Family Name <span class="form-required">*</span>
                        </label>
                        <div>
                            <input type="text" class="form-textbox"  id="last_name" name="last_name" size="20" value="" required/>
                        </div>
                    </li>

$("#myForm").validate({

    // Specify the validation rules
    rules: {

        //First Name
        first_name: "required",

        //Family Name
        last_name: "required"
   },

    // Specify the validation error messages
    messages: {

        //First Name
        first_name: "Please enter your first name",

        //Family Name
        last_name: "Please enter your family name"
   },

    submitHandler: function(form) {
        form.submit();
    }
});

});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/h2qxsws0/  Please look on this. And let me know what u need?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/h2qxsws0/3/ I want this, first name and last name to match the full name placed in signature, so concatenate both values and check if they are equal to the 1 field.

Comment: You can write a little hack if you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done a quick hack to solve this. It works well although this may not be the *preferred* way to do it.

- Add a hidden input `#fullname`
- Populate the hidden input with the value of first and last name separated by a space
- Validate the signature agianst the hidden input

```js
$("#name1, #name2").on("change", function() {
    $("#fullname").val( $("#name1").val() + " " + $("#name2").val() );
});

jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
  debug: true,
  success: "valid"
});

$( "#myform" ).validate({
  rules: {
    name1: "required",
    name2: "required",
    signature: {
      equalTo: "#fullname"
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform">
    <label for="1st name">1st name</label>
    <input id="name1" name="name1" />
    <br/>
    <label for="2 name">2 name</label>
    <input class="left" id="name2" name="name2" />
    <br/>
    <label for="2 name">Signature</label>
    <input class="left" id="signature" name="signature" />
    <input type="hidden" id="fullname" />
    <input type="submit" value="Validate!" />
</form>
```

**Edit:**

As for case-insensitivity, you would have to add a custom method to validator and do your check within the added method. Take a look at the following.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("anotherNotEqualTo", function(value, element, param) {
    return this.optional(element) || value.toLowerCase() === $(param).val().toLowerCase();
},  "Signature must be equal to your name!");

$( "#myform" ).validate({
  rules: {
    name1: "required",
    name2: "required",
    signature: {
        anotherNotEqualTo: "#fullname"
    }
  }
});
```

Here is a [link to the updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y46m59kh/), just in case.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I like your hack, it works well :) it is not really a hack, it is just like a 2 step simple validation rather then creating a whole method etc

Comment: Only issue with this is, if they use lower case or uppercase, it must match 100%, how to make jquery validate ignore letter case?

Answer (score 0):

Basically not. You need to write your own validator function. E. g. like this:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("concatEqualsTo",
                           function (value, element, params)
                           {
                              var concatedVal;
                              $(params).each(function(index, val)
                                             {
                                                concatedVal += $(val).val();
                                             }
                              );

                              return val === concatedVal;
                           }
);
```

This was just an example on the fly. Not sure if it works, but it should. Place this code at the end of your script before `$(document).ready` is called.

Edit: For documentation see here: http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod

You should also pass to it an array of elements you want to concat in jQuery Notation.

Comment: how would I apply a custom method to my validate() function?